# cdebootsrap-static fails on initramfs

Tags: debootstrap

From a fresh live cd of Ubuntu 12.04:

```
# enabling universe repository
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cdebootstrap-static
sudo cdebootstrap-static --debug -v --allow-unauthenticated --flavour minimal precise /mnt http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
```

Failed with this error:

```
O: Errors were encountered while processing:
O:   /var/cache/bootstrap/initramfs-tools_0.99ubuntu13_all.deb
D: Status: 256
E: Internal error: install
```

Any ideas why? Thanks

Comment: cdebootstrap isn't really maintained, use debootstrap instead.

Answer (score 1):

After further reading on `cdebootstrap vs debootstrap`, I finally opt for @psusi suggestion - use debootstrap instead of cdebootstrap. This worked:

```
sudo apt-get install deboostrap;
sudo debootstrap --arch=amd64 --variant=minbase precise /mnt http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
```